# JS array splice don't remove the index for some reason

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I'm sending :

```
for (var com = 0; com < 10; com++) {
        var op = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        combo = op[Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)];
        door1[com] = combo;
        op.splice(combo, 1);
        combo = op[Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)];
        door2[com] = combo;
        op.splice(combo, 1);
        combo = op[Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)];
        door3[com] = combo;
        op.splice(combo, 1);
        combo = op[Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)];
        door4[com] = combo;
        eim.print(op.toString());
}
```

Now when I print the op array. I should get only 1 value because I've deleted already the other indexes. with the splice.
but when I print the result 10 times. I find that some of the indexes didn't removed.
I'm trying to create 4 different combos. Each combo is different from the other one.

Comment: What do `door1`,`door2`,`door3`, etc mean? How they are previously declared? Give us more details, please.

Comment: `op[Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)]` can return an index that is greater than or equal to the array's length (since you're using the values stored in `op` instead of the actual random index you're computing).

Comment: and what is `eim.print()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the index of the item to remove it from the array, not the value

```js
var door1 = {},
  door2 = {},
  door3 = {},
  door4 = {};
for (var com = 0; com < 10; com++) {
  var op = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  door1[com] = getValue(op);
  door2[com] = getValue(op);
  door3[com] = getValue(op);
  door4[com] = getValue(op);
  snippet.log(JSON.stringify(op));
  console.log(op)
}

function getValue(array) {
  var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length),
    val = array[idx];
  array.splice(idx, 1);
  return val;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing is ,

```
Array.splice(combo,1);
```

now what it is trying to do is to splice an element from array whose index is `combo`, now combo can be any value, and it is not index.

you can try it by index, [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3etnfcbj/)

**code:**

```
door1={}
door2={}
door3={}
door4={}
var index=null;
for (var com = 0; com < 10; com++) {
        var op = [0, 1, 2, 3];
        index=Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)
        combo = op[index];
        door1[com] = combo;
        op.splice(index, 1);
        index=Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)
        combo = op[index];
        door2[com] = combo;
        op.splice(index, 1);
        index=Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)
        combo = op[index];
        door3[com] = combo;
        op.splice(index, 1);
        index=Math.floor(Math.random() * op.length)
        combo = op[index];
        door4[com] = combo;
        document.write(op.toString()+'<br>');
}
```

Comment: so, in this question `eim.print()` is `document.write(op.toString()+'<br>')`?

Comment: Thank you, you are correct!, my bad for not noticing XD

Answer (score 1):

Just take the spliced element for the door arrays. `Array.prototype.splice` returns an array, so for just one, take the first element, with index `[0]`.

The last assignment for `door4` does not need a calculation of random or so, just take the single element of the array `op`.

```js
var combo, com, door1 = [], door2 = [], door3 = [], door4 = [], op;
for (com = 0; com < 10; com++) {
    op = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    door1[com] = op.splice(Math.random() * op.length | 0, 1)[0];
    door2[com] = op.splice(Math.random() * op.length | 0, 1)[0];
    door3[com] = op.splice(Math.random() * op.length | 0, 1)[0];
    door4[com] = op[0];
}
document.write('door1: ' + door1 + '<br>');
document.write('door2: ' + door2 + '<br>');
document.write('door3: ' + door3 + '<br>');
document.write('door4: ' + door4 + '<br>');
```